# Xamarin forms AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter closes without error or exception

Tags: xamarin.forms

We have a Xamarin forms app that is closing during a background API call.  I didn't write much of the sync code on this project but I'm left troubleshooting it.  Here is a summary of what the code is doing:

1. an api call goes out and is returned successfully
2. the json string is serialized into a list of C# objects correctly.
3. the objects are passed to a method that maps them to a local class that only contains the properties we care about on the app.
4. after this mapping we insert these objects to a sql lite database.

At some point during 3 while looping through that list of objects and mapping them the app just closes without throwing any kind of exception.  I've tried ordering the objects to see if there is something related to the data that is causing the crash and I can't detect any pattern there.  Sometimes it crashes after the 15, 20th, 27th object, so I don't think it's related to a data issue.  The code here is pretty basic: a foreach loop and a basic method that assigns properties from one class to another class, and if it were a problem with the code I would expect to see an exception thrown.

I'm sure my first step is finding some Xamarin tricks for actually reporting what is causing the crash.  For what it's worth we've observed this behavior on both Android and iOS.

--Update--

I'm hopefully narrowing down the problem.  I found this bit of information from the Xamarin docs:

```
the framework will attempt to determine whether or not an adapter is making 
progress by monitoring its network activity over the course of a minute. If 
the network traffic over this window is close enough to zero the sync will 
be cancelled.
```

[Android.Content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter/)

My suspicion is that at the point that the app is closing the sync has long finished with any network calls but is still left processing all the mapping and database inserts with the resulting data.  So:

1. How can I tell if this is the case?  I tried adding the OnSyncCanceled() method that never gits hit in the debugger with the app closes.
2. It looks like he's spun this off on another thread, if this is the case, why would the whole app close, and not just the sync process?

Here is what is happening in the SyncAdapter

```
public class SyncAdapterImpl : AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter
{
    public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context, bool autoInitialize)
        : base(context, autoInitialize)
    {
    }

    public override void OnSyncCanceled()
    {
        base.OnSyncCanceled();
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
    }

    public override void OnPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new PlatformModule(), new CoreModule());
        var syncService = kernel.Get<SyncService>();
        SyncResultSummary syncResultSummary = new SyncResultSummary();
        if (!extras.GetBoolean(ContentResolver.SyncExtrasUpload))
        {
            syncService.UpdateProfile().Wait();
            var task = syncService.DownloadJobs();
            task.Wait();
            syncResultSummary = task.Result;
        }

        // send notifications with results          
    }
}
```

--Update 2--

I noticed that adding `Process = ":sync"` to the `SyncAdapterService` class prevents the whole app from being killed, however, the sync itself fails now.

```
[Service(Label = "SyncAdapterService", Exported = true, Process = ":sync")]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "android.content.SyncAdapter" })]
[MetaData("android.content.SyncAdapter", Resource = "@xml/syncadapter")]
public class SyncAdapterService : Service
{
    private SyncAdapterImpl _syncAdapter;
    private object _syncAdapterMutex = new object();

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        lock(_syncAdapterMutex)
        {
            if (_syncAdapter == null)
                _syncAdapter = new SyncAdapterImpl(this.ApplicationContext, true);
        }
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return _syncAdapter.SyncAdapterBinder;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked the application output / device logs for any crash information?  Are you sure that it's not caused by an unhandled exception?

Comment: I would start commenting out the code and see what causing that and start with insertion to DB.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that after the SyncAdapter finished the API call it was done making any network traffic but was still left with a bunch of processing and db writes.  Xamarin was seeing no network traffic and saying "hey, you're done syncing" and then killing the process while it was still running, which was the same process the whole app was running under.  Nothing explicitly warns you when that happens, it just happens.

So what I've done is pulled back just a small object for each record with the id and updated time, and then loop through them one by one (you can't do it in parallel because you run back into the same problem) - it seems like the solution is to keep some network activity humming the whole time you still need to do work.

It would probably be nicer to be able to pull back the data and pass it off to something else, but I'd have to research the xamarin way of doing things a bit more to figure that out